# Mootools: add HTML text to an Element

Tags: javascript, mootools

i'm using mootools.js, i have this code:

```
this.html.chat_title = new Element('span', {
    'id' : 'chat_title',
    html : 'this is the title'
}).inject(this.html.container);
```

The problem is:

```
span id="chat_title" html="this is the title"
```

as you see it doesn't put the text inside the HTML of the tag but as an attribute.

What is wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is because there is no [Element.Properties.html](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element-Properties:html) setter and getter in MooTools 1.1.2. You can use the setHTML method instead:

```
this.html.chat_title = new Element('span', {
    'id': 'chat_title'
}).setHTML('this is the title').inject(this.html.container);
```

Otherwise create your own setter and getter or update to a newer version of MooTools.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid code, so my only advice is to try downloading a full version of the MooTools Core, to make sure you're not missing a needed component (in case you downloaded using the Core Builder).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.. are you using MooTools 1.1.2? I see the same on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EsbVW/). `html` gets added as an attribute, instead of element's `innerHTML`.

I'd suggest you try upgrading if that is the case. 1.1.2 has been old for quite sometime now.

Comment: Thats ok, if he's under 1.1.x, there is `.setHTML` and `.setText` methods. i am not saying he shouldn't upgrade, but there's no real need to (for this sake alone anyway). http://jsfiddle.net/EsbVW/2/